# How to prevent multiple dialogs on gridview multitouch

Tags: android, gridview, android-alertdialog, multi-touch

I have a grid view of images in my android app. Clicking on each image opens a dialog showing more info about the image. I just realized if I simultaneously click more than one image with my fingers then multiple dialogs (one for each of the image) pop up on top of each other. How can I disable this and ensure only one dialog pops up at one time.

Note: This is different from tapping on the same image quickly and having identical dialogs open (a problem I fixed using http://www.jorgecoca.com/android-quick-tip-avoid-opening-multiple-dialogs-when-tapping-an-element/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dialog is `myDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // User clicked OK button
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // User cancelled the dialog
    }
});
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

AlertDialog myDialog = builder.create();
```

On click of grid item show the dialog like this

```
if(!myDialog.isShowing())
    myDialog.show();
```

If you are creating your dialog when user click on the grid view item then create the dialog at global level and use that.